# Activity scene transition not working when starting an existing singleTask Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I'm applying scene transitions to Activities. Says that I have 2 Activities: `MainActivity` with launch mode `singleTask` and `NextActivity` with launch mode `standard`. They have the same theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And at the following scenarios:

1. `MainActivity` starts `NextActivity` via:

   ```
   startActivity(Intent(this,NextActivity::class.java), ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle())
   ```
2. After scenario 1, `NextActivity` returns to `MainActivity` via `finishAfterTransition()`
3. After scenario 1, `NextActivity` returns to `MainActivity` via:

   ```
   startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java), ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle())
   ```

Since `MainActivity` is in `singleTask` launch mode, 2 and 3 should result in the same task stack behavior: `NextActivity` is finished and user is brought back to `MainActivity`.

Now the problem is, in 1 and 2, the transitions are played correctly, but in 3, the transitions are not played. In detail, `NextActivity` leaves with default animation (slide down off the screen), while `MainActivity` is left transparent with the wallpaper visible, not iteractable though.

After adding some `println` lines to the transition listeners, I found that in 3, the exit transition for `NextActivity` is started, though not displayed properly. And the reenter transition for `MainActivity` is not started.

What's the cause to such strange behavior?

For reference, the code (in Kotlin) of the Activities is [here](https://gist.github.com/perqin/a3d9ba90fffed27af871e73681fe4a0c).